Why does this simple and small Java code runs 30x faster in all Graal JVMs but not on any Oracle JVMs?
I'm not compiling anything to native, in other words, I'm not using native-image from GraalVM. I'm just running the same Java class (same Java bytecode) with GraalVM and then running the same Java class (same Java bytecode) with regular Oracle JVMs.
It does not matter which version of Java I use or platform (I tested in Linux and Mac). GraalVM is always much faster (30x) than any other regular JVM.
It looks like the regular JVMs are not optimizing the method correctly with their JIT. Notice that the method is very simple and small.
Does anyone have any insight of why that's the case and how I could fix that in my regular JVM? The only workaround at the moment is to migrate to GraalVM. It is very easy to compile and run the code below to reproduce the issue. Just compile and then run first with an Oracle JVM and then with any Graal JVM to see the difference.
public class OracleJvm23MathBug {

    // simple and small amount of math
    // =====> should be optimized/compiled/inlined for sure!
    private static final long doSomething(int load, int i) {
        long x = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < load; j++) {
            long pow = (i % 8) * (i % 16);
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                x += pow;
            } else {
                x -= pow;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    /*
     * Execute this with OpenJDK/Zulu/Oracle JVM 23 => average 215 nanoseconds
     * Now execute this with Graal23 JVM 23 => average 7 nanoseconds
     * 
     * This bug can be observed in any platform (I tested on Linux and Mac)
     * 
     * $ java -version 
     * java version "23.0.1" 2024-10-15 
     * Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 23.0.1+11-39)
     * Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)
     * 
     * $ java -cp . OracleJvm23MathBug
     * Value computed: -550000000000
     * Measurements: 10000000| Avg Time: 215 nanos | Min Time: 83 nanos | Max Time: 199750 nanos
     * 
     * $ java -version
     * java version "23.0.1" 2024-10-15
     * Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 23.0.1+11.1 (build 23.0.1+11-jvmci-b01)
     * Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 23.0.1+11.1 (build 23.0.1+11-jvmci-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
     * 
     * $ java -cp . OracleJvm23MathBug
     * Value computed: -550000000000
     * Measurements: 10000000| Avg Time: 7 nanos | Min Time: 0 nanos | Max Time: 178625 nanos
     */
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        final int iterations = 10_000_000;
        final int load = 10_000;
        NanoBench bench = new NanoBench();
        long computed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            bench.mark();
            computed += doSomething(load, i);
            bench.measure();
        }
        System.out.println("Value computed: " + computed);
        bench.printResults();
    }

    private static class NanoBench {

        private int measurements;
        private long totalTime, minTime, maxTime, time;
        private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);

        NanoBench() {
            reset();
        }

        public final void reset() {
            totalTime = time = measurements = 0;
            maxTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
            minTime = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        public final void mark() {
            time = System.nanoTime();
        }

        public final void measure() {
            long lastNanoTime = System.nanoTime() - time;
            totalTime += lastNanoTime;
            minTime = lastNanoTime < minTime ? lastNanoTime : minTime;
            maxTime = lastNanoTime > maxTime ? lastNanoTime : maxTime;
            measurements++;
        }

        public final void printResults() {
            sb.setLength(0);
            sb.append("Measurements: ").append(measurements);
            sb.append("| Avg Time: ").append((long) (totalTime / (double) measurements)).append(" nanos");
            sb.append(" | Min Time: ").append(minTime).append(" nanos");
            sb.append(" | Max Time: ").append(maxTime).append(" nanos\n\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) System.out.print(sb.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}


Migrate. Oracle JVMs aren't the fastest, even if the difference usually isn't THAT big

@Hobbamok Unfortunately I cannot migrate at the moment. I would like to understand what is happening.

You really should use JMH

To be thorough, try the Eclipse OpenJ9 JVM as well.

I wouldn't trust any measurement not done with JMH.  Diffing System.nanoTime() yourself is almost certainly a reason not to trust your benchmark.

If JMH were used, this simple, self-contained reproducible executable would no longer be a simple, self-contained, reproducible executable (well, at least no longer simple and self-contained). Besides, JMH itself does the benchmark by diffing System.nanotime() albeit in a sophisticated way; and I'm sure its results would also show this difference in performance. At least these benchmarks use lots of iterations (10 million), so warmup is catered for, and include a minimum as well as an average time. The minimum would certainly be post-JIT.

First of all, are you quite sure you don't have the the compilers set with different options, like bounds checking, or invisible debug calls that allow single step, or something?

Good morning @MissUnderstands. I think you didn't understand. This is Java code. I compile only once to Java bytecode an then I execute the same bytecode with two different JVMs.

@MissUnderstands You said: You have repeated calls to extend a string by appending but please check the code again and you will see that the string concat is called only once at the end and it is not being measured.

That is true, the use of StringBuilder has nothing to do with the performance measurement. However, that is a very strange and unnecessarily complicated way to print the results. I would have just used a single System.out.printf for that.

@k314159 I think the OP did that not to create any garbage. The StringBuilder is being re-used and toString() it never called. To avoid calling toString() to print the results, he simply prints character by character in the last line: for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) System.out.print(sb.charAt(i));. By the way, I have a YouTube video about garbage-free programming where I talk about some of the tricks we use to avoid GC overhead. If you leave any comments there with your thoughts and feedback, I'll answer it.

Ok ty! thankyou!

GraalVM is using a brand new JIT implementation written in Java. I wouldn't say it is better or worse than the HotSpot C2 JIT compiler, which by the way is very old and written in C++. As Adam Ruka says in this blog post:

The JIT compiler that is used in most distributions of the JVM is
HotSpot. It’s the first Java JIT compiler, and thus its codebase is
quite old. It’s also written in C++; and since a JIT compiler is a
very complex piece of technology, C++’s unmanaged nature means every
potential bug in its code can lead to very serious JVM issues, like
runtime crashes, security vulnerabilities, or memory leaks. All of
those factors mean that developing HotSpot is so difficult that only a
few experts in the world can realistically do it. This slow pace of
development means that HotSpot lags behind the current state of the
art when it comes to supporting all of the newest optimizations.

But not all is lost; you can use the Graal JIT compiler with the latest Oracle JVM 23:
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseJVMCICompiler

If you run your code with that option you will see that it runs very fast.

For the record, here are my results using CoralBench:
HotSpot C2 JIT
Measurements: 10,000,000 | Warm-Up: 0 | Iterations: 10,000,000
Avg Time: 376.860 nanos | Min Time: 125.000 nanos | Max Time: 151.625 micros
75% = [avg: 368.000 nanos, max: 375.000 nanos]
90% = [avg: 369.000 nanos, max: 416.000 nanos]
99% = [avg: 374.000 nanos, max: 500.000 nanos]
99.9% = [avg: 375.000 nanos, max: 583.000 nanos]
99.99% = [avg: 375.000 nanos, max: 5.083 micros]
99.999% = [avg: 376.000 nanos, max: 16.875 micros]

HotSpot Graal JIT
Measurements: 10,000,000 | Warm-Up: 0 | Iterations: 10,000,000
Avg Time: 8.190 nanos | Min Time: 0.000 nano | Max Time: 161.000 micros
75% = [avg: 0.000 nano, max: 0.000 nano]
90% = [avg: 0.000 nano, max: 41.000 nanos]
99% = [avg: 4.000 nanos, max: 42.000 nanos]
99.9% = [avg: 5.000 nanos, max: 42.000 nanos]
99.99% = [avg: 5.000 nanos, max: 21.708 micros]
99.999% = [avg: 7.000 nanos, max: 24.625 micros]

Semeru/OpenJ9 JIT (from IBM)
Measurements: 10,000,000 | Warm-Up: 0 | Iterations: 10,000,000
Avg Time: 3.354 micros | Min Time: 3.166 micros | Max Time: 2.390 millis
75% = [avg: 3.286 micros, max: 3.292 micros]
90% = [avg: 3.292 micros, max: 3.334 micros]
99% = [avg: 3.305 micros, max: 4.500 micros]
99.9% = [avg: 3.336 micros, max: 12.458 micros]
99.99% = [avg: 3.347 micros, max: 19.958 micros]
99.999% = [avg: 3.350 micros, max: 106.250 micros]


Also, not surprisingly, people who are interested in Java performance are more likely to be competent at Java than C++.

I know, but this sounds a lot like C++ => C++’s unmanaged nature means every potential bug in its code can lead to very serious JVM issues, like runtime crashes, security vulnerabilities, or memory leaks.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont That's true. You seem like an expert in C++. Please check my question here (which has a bounty) to see if you can offer any insight => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79268109/c-implementation-of-a-simple-map-slower-than-equivalent-implementation-in-java
